# boost fusion and const correctness

Tags: c++, constants, boost-fusion

I am learning boost fusion and am trying to take a view of a `std::vector<boost::fusion::vector<int,double,double> >`. The code appears simple but I appear to be running into some problems with const. I clearly misunderstand something about const and would love for someone to explain where I am going wrong.

The code:

```
template<int N, class T>
struct viewTraits{
    typedef typename T::value_type etype;
    typedef typename boost::fusion::result_of::as_nview<etype, N>::type netype;
    typedef std::vector<netype> result_type;
};

template <int N, typename T>
typename viewTraits<N,T>::result_type c( T const &t ) 
{
   typename viewTraits<N, T>::result_type retVal;  
    for (typename T::const_iterator it(t.begin());it<t.end();++it){
        retVal.push_back(fusion::as_nview<N>(*it));
    } 
    return retVal;
}

template <typename Container>
typename Container::value_type sum( Container const &container )
{
    typedef typename Container::value_type value_type;
    return std::accumulate( container.begin(), container.end(), value_type() );
}

int main(){
    typedef fusion::vector<int, double, double>             row;
    typedef std::vector<row>                                                container;

    container x;
    b( x, 200 );
    std::cout << sum(c<1>(x)) << std::endl;
}
```

The code fails to compile at `retVal.push_back()` because of an issue with casting const. I tried several permutations of removing and adding some const keywords but have not been successful at programming by permutation and would rather understand what I am doing.

Anyone have any thoughts? BTW the `const` in the function definition of `sum` and `c` must stay.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that `b` fills `x` which is a `std::vector<fusion::vector<int, double, double> >`

EDIT2: The corrected code:

```
template<int N, class T>
struct viewTraits{
    typedef typename T::value_type etype;
    typedef typename fusion::result_of::as_nview<etype, N>::type netype;
    typedef typename fusion::result_of::at_c<netype,0>::type reference;
    typedef typename boost::decay<reference>::type value_type;
    typedef std::vector<value_type> result_type;
};

template <int N, typename T>
typename viewTraits<N,T>::result_type c( T const &t )
{
    typename viewTraits<N,T>::result_type retVal;

    for(typename T::const_iterator it(t.begin()); it<t.end();++it){
        retVal.push_back(fusion::deref(fusion::begin(fusion::as_nview<N>(*it))));
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: Is `*(const T*) const`? Drop the const with a `const_cast`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two immediate problems with your code:

- you compute `fusion::as_nview<N>(*it)` and try to store it as if it were a `fusion::result_of::as_nview<T::value_type, N>::type`; in truth it is a `fusion::result_of::as_nview<T::value_type const, N>::type` (`*it` has type `T::const_reference`); this is the source of your `const`-related errors.
- you try to accumulate the resulting views, but, as far I can tell from [the Fusion docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/view/nview.html), valid operations on such a view are mostly those of a Fusion Random Access Sequence. In particular you can't add two views together, or default construct one. Here's a lead to a possible fix (by no means the only way though), not actually tested:

  ```
  typedef typename Container::value_type view_type;
  typedef typename fusion::result_of::at_c<view_type, 0>::type reference;
  // boost::decay is from Boost.TypeTraits
  typedef typename boost::decay<reference>::type value_type;
  value_type zero = 0;
  return std::accumulate(container.begin(), container.end(), zero, add_views());
  ```

  where `add_views` is a functor that returns something in the spirit of `lhs + at<0>(rhs)`. Note that this solution only really makes sense if you intend for `c` to make views of length exactly one.

Comment: Regarding your second point. I am unable to change the method `sum` but am allowed to change the type of `Container`. I have not yet been able to adapt your code snippet to fit into my function `c`. Any thoughts?

Comment: Thanks for the tips Luc, I was able to use your code snippet to sort out my question.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Sequence` type isn't `T::value_type`, it's `const T::value_type`.  Try writing `typedef const typename T::value_type etype;`.

Comment: That changed the type to `fusion::vector<const int, const double, const double>` which threw a number of const related compile errors

Comment: they are too long to post here...lots of template related stuff. The essence is that your suggestion makes a `fusion::vector<const int, const double, const double>` instead of the `const fusion::vector<int, double, double>` that the compiler expects. Another attempt at programming by permutation based on your suggestion has not yielded the correct type